# IOS Frank Build Fail

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4.5, frank

I'm trying to build Frank for an IOS project i'm currently creating but i keep getting build errors failures with Frank while Xcode can build the project fine.

Maybe some important details: 
- I'm using a library that i compiled for the ipad so the project won't build for the simulator. 
- i changed the valid architecture to armv7 (not armv7, armv7s) 
- programming in ios 6.0
- using xcode 4.5

I downloaded and installed Frank

After i go to the directory of my project (with terminal) 
i typed the following

```
1. frank setup
2. frank build //something fails here
```

I get the following error

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET MyProj OF PROJECT MyProj WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386,          VALID_ARCHS=armv7).


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1241:in `mkdir': No such file or directory -     /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-    Code/new/MyProj/Frank/frankified_build/Frankified.app (Errno::ENOENT)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1241:in `copy'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:452:in `copy_entry'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1331:in `traverse'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:449:in `copy_entry'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:424:in `cp_r'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1402:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1418:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1400:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:423:in `cp_r'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/frank-cucumber-1.1.3/lib/frank-cucumber/cli.rb:85:in `build'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `send'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/frank-cucumber-1.1.3/bin/frank:5
from /usr/bin/frank:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/frank:19
```

After some searching i found a link where someone said i could give the architecture with the buil so i did

```
1. frank setup //not really necessary cause i did it before 
2. frank build --arch armv7 //giving the architecture with the command
```

But it gives the following error

```
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET MyProj OF PROJECT MyProj WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

ProcessInfoPlistFile Frank/frankified_build/./MyProj.app/Info.plist MyProj/MyProj-Info.plist
cd /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin"
builtin-infoPlistUtility MyProj/MyProj-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj/Frank/frankified_build/./MyProj.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj/Frank/frankified_build/./MyProj.app/Info.plist

SymLink build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app Frank/frankified_build/./MyProj.app
cd /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin"
/bin/ln -sf /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-  Code/new/MyProj/Frank/frankified_build/./MyProj.app /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app

ProcessPCH   /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-ghaenwxjeomtsdddtxghgmmdgysv/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/user/Desktop/mobile_hr_ios_svn/trunk/mobile_hr_ios/03-Code/new/MyProj
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/MyProj.hmap -I/Users/user/Desktop/vn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Idcmtk/include -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/config -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmdata -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmimage -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmimgle -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmjpls -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmnet -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmpstat -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmqrdb -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmsign -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmsr -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmtls -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmwlm -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/ofstd -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/openssl -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmdata/libi2d -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/config -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/helpers -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/spi -I/usr/include/openssl -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-ghaenwxjeomtsdddtxghgmmdgysv/MyProj-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-ghaenwxjeomtsdddtxghgmmdgysv/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-ghaenwxjeomtsdddtxghgmmdgysv/MyProj-Prefix.pch.d
clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=6.0'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

ProcessPCH++ /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-fcetjlzwprtljocwgscvlozrhdco/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wno-arc-abi -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/MyProj.hmap -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Idcmtk/include -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/config -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmdata -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmimage -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmimgle -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmjpeg -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmjpls -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmnet -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmpstat -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmqrdb -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmsign -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmsr -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmtls -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmwlm -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/ofstd -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/openssl -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/dcmdata/libi2d -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/config -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/helpers -Idcmtk/include/dcmtk/oflog/spi -I/usr/include/openssl -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/MyProj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/build/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-fcetjlzwprtljocwgscvlozrhdco/MyProj-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/user/Desktop/svn/trunk/03-Code/new/MyProj/MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-fcetjlzwprtljocwgscvlozrhdco/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-fcetjlzwprtljocwgscvlozrhdco/MyProj-Prefix.pch.d
clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=6.0'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH   /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-ghaenwxjeomtsdddtxghgmmdgysv/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
ProcessPCH++ /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/com.apple.Xcode.0/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyProj-Prefix-fcetjlzwprtljocwgscvlozrhdco/MyProj-Prefix.pch.pth MyProj/MyProj-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
     run  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :CFBundleIdentifier   yang.apps..MyProj.frankified' Info.plist from "./Frank/frankified_build/Frankified.app"
     run  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :CFBundleDisplayName Frankified' Info.plist from "./Frank/frankified_build/Frankified.app"
```

Can someone help me build frank for the iPad?